# C: Keep taking integers as input and terminate after two consecutive negative integers

Tags: c, io

I want to take standard input from user, specifically integers, and keep taking input until the user enters two negative integers in a row.

Example of such inputs:

```
1
2
3
16
-5
6
-2
-3
```

The program terminates since -2 and -3 are two consecutive negative integers. How do I go about doing this in C? I'm fairly new to it. I don't need a solution, just some hints would be helpful as to which approach would be most efficient.

Here is my code, but is there a better way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int counter = 0;
int num;

do{
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num < 0){
        counter++;
    } else {
        counter = 0;
    }

}
while (counter != 2);




}
```

Comment: Store a "last" value, and if the current value is negative and the last value was also negative, stop?

Comment: Edit: I added my code, thank you for pointing it out @AntonH, and ShadowRanger I might try that!!

Comment: So you have a working solution but are looking for a "better" way? There aren't really many different ways to do it. You'ld need a loop and 2 variables, either before-last and last values entered as ShadowRanger suggested, or last value entered and counter, like you did it. It's probably possible with a single variable, but most likely convoluted to work out.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there isn't a better way.
It is a very simple and basic program and the only thing that you can do is change the type of the loop, for example using while or for loop; but it will be the same.